# How would you round up or give a minimum number to a fraction?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm returning the size of a file using

```
var info = new System.IO.FileInfo(@"" + file + "");
```

The problem is, with very small files, if I have this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Length is {0} KB", info.Length/1024);
```

it will return "0KB".  I'd like those to return "1KB" instead.

Can this be done without writing a whole other function?  I'm hoping it can be done in some formula statement, but I'm still new to C# and don't know the syntax well.

Comment: Use `(info.Length + 1023) / 1024`

Comment: Wont that round up every number by 1?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably show that value as a decimal.

```
Console.WriteLine("Length is {0:0.00} KB", info.Length/(decimal)1024);
```

So now you could get an output more like:

> Length is 0.24 KB

---

You could do a conditional statement like:

```
int length = info.Length / 1024;
Console.WriteLine("Length is {0} KB", length == 0 ? 1 : length);
```

---

You could take the decimal idea but just always round the value up.
So 0.01 would show as 1KB and 1.01 would show as 2KB etc.

```
int length = (int)Math.Ceiling(info.Length / (decimal)1024);
Console.WriteLine("Length is {0} KB", length);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Length is {0} KB", Math.Round((double)info.Length/(double)1024);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want 1kb only for files which have a length, but 0 for files which are actually empty and the floor of the floating point for all others, you could use the following:

```
Console.WriteLine("Length is {0} KB", info.Length > 0 && info.Length < 1024 ? 1 : info.Length/1024
```